# `getInitialProps` is not working on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am receiving the desired `query` object value when I come to this page via other links but when I do page refresh I get an empty `query` object. Can anyone explain why is this happening and how to resolve this problem?

```
Example.getInitialProps = ({ query }) => {
    console.log(query);
    return { query };
};
```

I am using the query object inside the same component like this

```
const Example = () => {
   //Other things...

    useEffect(() => {
       console.log(query)
    })
}
```

Comment: You should show how is the inital value getting populated

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: I have made changes, is it sufficient? console is just for debugging.

Comment: Show some actual code, this is not enough.